# PHP cookie with same name but different paths

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I want to check a cookie with name "subscription" and there are 3 cookies with this name but has different paths as follows
path 1 is /
path 2 is /customer/checkout/
path 3 is /customer/register/

now if i want to apply an if condition if subscription is set then the condition works only for path 1.How do I make it work for all three paths???

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reliably check the path of a cookie in PHP (or any serverside language for that matter) as most or at least some browsers don't send the path for the cookie. They only send key-value pairs.

If reliability/cross browser support isn't a must, you could check if the path of the cookies is send with the request headers. Use a method like

```
<?php

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: thank you for the quick reply...I checked the path using firefox. i don't want to know the paths I already know that I just want to know if there is any way to check(if set or not) all three cookies separately.

Comment: There is no way to do that serverside, most browsers don't send this information to the server (the path). They only send a key-value pair or nothing when the clientside decides there's no value for the path.

You could look into a Javascript based solution where you check the cookies clientside (though i don't know if that's possible asswell)